# Ubuntu 14.10 no network found

Tags: networking, 14.10

This morning I have updated to the latest version of Ubuntu 14.10 and when I booted it , it cannot find network. I have installed on a desktop so I am using a wired connection.

When I go to my network settings it gives me a pop-up menu that tell me the following "The system network services are not compatible with this version". How do I fix this?  I have tried the normal things, rebooting the router and new Ethernet cables and all that.

Do I have to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 again, or is there a fix around this? I wish not to reinstall Ubuntu since it is a pain to reconfigure everything again

Answer (score 2):

Same thing here,

I think the initd scripts are executed out of sequence.
And my nfs is not mounted because of no network when fstab is executed.

After waiting 120 secs "for network configuration" I got network back by:

```
ijbd@ZEN:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

got my nas=nfs back with:

```
ijbd@ZEN:~$ sudo mount -a
```

gmail and LinkedIn applets also affected, but I can login via browser.

I avoid the startup delay using Suspend rather than Shut Down.

Comment: I have reloaded back to 14.04, took me took long to find an ans, thank you hope this helps someone!